# Menu Contexto. Problemas com a opção Excluir

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Vou narrar o meu problema: Ao adicionar algumas imagens na tela, eu seleciono uma imagem com o botão direito do mouse, daí aparece o menu contexto, e eu desisto de excluir, PORÉM.. a função de apagar continua valendo para a última imagem que eu selecionei, ou seja, se eu clicar fora da imagem e clicar em apagar, ela apaga a última imagem que eu tinha selecionado. Eu gostaria apenas de bloquear a opção de apagar quando eu clicasse fora da imagem (mas continuasse mostrando, só que sem deixar eu clicar). Eu tentei usar o "pointer-events:none" no ".apagar", mas não consegui fazer funcionar direito. Estou a muito tempo nisso, não sei o que fazer.. Desde já, já sou imensamente grato a todas as respostas.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Função para carregar a imagem
  var counter = 0;
  var $allContainers = $("#allContainers");
  var $dropzone = $("#dropzone");
  $(".apagar").css({
    color: "gray",
    "pointer-events": "none",
  });

  // Adicione a função de arrastar e soltar na dropzone
  $dropzone.on("dragover", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $dropzone.addClass("hover");
  });

  $dropzone.on("dragleave", function () {
    $dropzone.removeClass("hover");
  });

  $dropzone.on("drop", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $dropzone.removeClass("hover");

    var file = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      var newContainer = $("<div>", {
        id: "container",
        class: "imgContainer",
      });

      var newImg = $("<img>", {
        class: "flutuante draggable",
        src: e.target.result,
        display: "none",
        css: { display: "none" },
      }).on("load", function () {
        newContainer.width($(this).width());
        newContainer.height($(this).height());

        var scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
        var scrollX = $(window).scrollLeft();
        var dropY = event.clientY + scrollY - newContainer.height() / 2;
        var dropX = event.clientX + scrollX - newContainer.width() / 2;

        newContainer.css({
          position: "fixed",
          top: dropY + "px",
          left: dropX + "px",
        });

        $(this).css({
          display: "block",
        });
      });

      newContainer.append(newImg);
      $allContainers.append(newContainer);

      // Função para mover o contêiner e a imagem
      var dragging = false;
      var offsetX, offsetY;

      newContainer.on("mousedown", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dragging = true;

        offsetY = newContainer.offset().top - e.clientY;
        offsetX = newContainer.offset().left - e.clientX;
      });

      $(document)
        .on("mousemove", function (e) {
          if (dragging) {
            newContainer.offset({
              top: e.clientY + offsetY,
              left: e.clientX + offsetX,
            });
          }
        })
        .on("mouseup", function () {
          dragging = false;
        });

      counter++;

      $(newContainer).on("mousedown", function (e) {
        $(".apagar").css({
          color: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.788)",

          "pointer-events": "",
        }); // habilita o evento de clique do elemento .apagar

        $(".apagar")
          .off("click")
          .on("click", function (evento) {
            if (evento.button === 0) {
              evento.preventDefault(); // previne o menu padrão de aparecer
              newContainer.remove();
            }
          });
      });

      //Style
      $(".flutuante").on("mouseup", function (event) {
        if (event.button == 2) {
          $(this).css("transform", "scale(2)");
          $(document).on("mouseup", onMouseUpDocument);
        }
      });
      function onMouseUpDocument(event) {
        if (event.button == 0) {
          $(".flutuante").css("transform", "");
          $(document).off("mouseup", onMouseUpDocument);
        }
      }
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });

  //Menu Contexto
  window.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {
    $(".rightclickmenu")
      .css({
        "margin-left": e.clientX,
        "margin-top": e.clientY,
      })
      .show();

    e.preventDefault();

    window.addEventListener("click", function () {
      $(".rightclickmenu").hide();
    });
  });

  // Adicione a função de arrastar e soltar
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    containment: "parent",
  });
});
```

```css
/* Define a cor de fundo do body */
html,
body {
  background-color: #2c2f32;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Define as propriedades do elemento flutuante */
.flutuante {
  width: 10vw;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

/* Define as propriedades do elemento flutuante quando o mouse estiver sobre ele */
.flutuante:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}

/* Define as propriedades do elemento flutuante quando ele estiver ativo (clicado) */
.flutuante:active {
  transform: none;
}

/* Define as propriedades do menu de clique direito */
.rightclickmenu {
  border: 1px solid #494c4e;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #393c3f;
  color: aliceblue;
  display: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#dropzone {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#allContainers {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Define as propriedades do objeto que dispara o menu de clique direito quando clicado */
#rightclickobject {
  width: 168px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.15s;
}
/* Define as propriedades do objeto que dispara o menu de clique direito quando o mouse estiver sobre ele */
#rightclickobject:hover {
  width: 168px;
  background-color: #88898d;
  color: white;
}

#rightclickobject.apagar:hover {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Aplicação Web</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="rightclickmenu">
      <div id="rightclickobject" onclick="window.open('http://www.exatas.tk')">
        Portal de Exatas
      </div>
      <div
        id="rightclickobject"
        onclick="window.open('http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/38968/vme?tab=profile')"
      >
        Vme SOpt
      </div>
      <div id="rightclickobject">Delete</div>
      <div id="rightclickobject" class="apagar" onclick="">Apagar</div>
    </div>

    <div id="dropzone">
      <div id="allContainers" class="allContainers"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Dentro do evento mousemove podemos fazer um ciclo pelos containers e se o cursor estiver dentro de algum container ativamos a opção delete, se não estiver desativamos.

```
$(document)
    .on("mousemove", function (e) {
    if (dragging) {
        newContainer.offset({
        top: e.clientY + offsetY,
        left: e.clientX + offsetX,
        });
    }

    
    $.each($allContainers.children(), function (i, val) {
        if (
            e.pageX >= $(val).offset().left &&
            e.pageX <= $(val).offset().left + $(val).width() &&
            e.pageY >= $(val).offset().top &&
            e.pageY <= $(val).offset().top + $(val).height()
        ) {
            $(".apagar").css({
                color: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.788)",
                "pointer-events": "",
            });
        } else {
            $(".apagar").css({
                color: "gray",
                "pointer-events": "none",
            });
        }
    });

    })
    .on("mouseup", function () {
    dragging = false;
    });
```